# Tracking (uniform spacing) between 2D elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

**The problem I am solving:**

- I select multiple 2D SVG elements in an editor(the elements
  are in arbitrary positions on my canvas).
- I run the function `calcMultiTrack()` *(see below)*.
- The elements should now have equal spacing between them equivalent to
  the `trackingAmount` parameter I passed when executing
  `calcMultiTrack()`. Spacing means only width-wise.

---

*A live demonstration of what I mean(this is a demo of the function I built, at work):*

[image]

**Some additional notes:**

- `calcMultiTrack()` uses a global variable, `multiselectedCopy`. This
  is an array that holds all the elements I have currently
  multi-selected.
- The algo must handle negative spacing (*negative `trackingAmount`*)
- The most-left item in a multiselection does not move. The tracking is calculated by figuring out how much spacing each element has from
  the previous one(starting from most-left) and then moving each
  element until the `trackingAmount` has been reached.

---

*There are 2 utility functions which are not defined in the code below.*

- `svgCanvas.moveSingleElement` *(moves an element by a certain x,y value
  which as passed as parameters)*
- `svgCanvas.getStrokedBBox` *(returns only x,y,width,height values for an element)*

---

**What I want to solve.**

1. Well, is this the best way? Are there any bottlenecks?

   > The user drags a slider to adjust tracking. Because the calculations
   >   take some time as they are, I [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing/4298672#4298672) the slider until the user stops
   >   sliding. Otherwise the browser hangs/is choppy. If this has many
   >   bottlenecks that could be eliminated, I could have the user dragging
   >   the slider and seeing the results in real-time. This will make it far
   >   better for the user since *immediate feedback is much better for such
   >   type of fine-adjustments.*
2. Element handling

   > Too much negative spacing jumbles up the letters. Not all elements
   >   have equal width so applying negative tracking can move an element
   >   (e.g the comma **(,)** in Hello **,** World), to a position that is
   >   wrong - less x position than it's previous letter which is (O) in this
   >   case. So when re-applying positive tracking the result becomes Hell,O
   >   World(*a lil bit of irony here*).
3. Most importantly, robustness

   > This might be a reason to downvote this question since I'm not sure I
   >   can explain what I mean here. This 'algorithm' is destined for a
   >   client, so I would like some expert second opinion before
   >   demonstrating it live

**What I have so far:**

```
function calcMultiTrack() {

      //Startup Variables
        var trackTolerance = 0.01;
        var compPrecision = 2; 


        //Get value from input element. How much spacing?
        var trackingAmount = parseInt($("#tracking").val());

        //Define new empty array
        var selItemsDimArray = [];

        //Push into new array the same elements as multiSelectedCopy but with more properties per element(x2,y2 is calculated here)
        for (var i = multiselectedCopy.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            var bb = svgCanvas.getStrokedBBox([multiselectedCopy[i]]); //getStrokedBBox returns x,y,width,height for an element.

            selItemsDimArray.push({
                'examinedElem': multiselectedCopy[i],
                'x': bb.x,
                'y': bb.y,
                'x2': (bb.x + bb.width),
                'y2': (bb.y + bb.height),
                'height': bb.height,
                'width': bb.width
            });

        };

        //Sort array starting from most left(smallest x position meaning it's the most left element.)
        selItemsDimArray.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.x - b.x;
        });


        //Most left item does not move so define now a calc distance of 0. calc distance is the distance we will have to move an element later.
        selItemsDimArray[0]['calcDistance'] = 0;


        //Calculate and push diff - diff is the distance of an element from the previous(next smallest x position)
        for (var i = 1; i < selItemsDimArray.length; i++) {
            var current = selItemsDimArray[i];
            var previous = selItemsDimArray[i - 1];
            var diff = current.x - previous.x2;

            selItemsDimArray[i]['diff'] = diff;


            //Handle negative diffs (e.g letter has negative spacing from previous)
            if (diff < 0) {
                selItemsDimArray[i]['calcDistance'] = (trackingAmount + (-diff)) + selItemsDimArray[i - 1].calcDistance
            } else {
                selItemsDimArray[i]['calcDistance'] = (trackingAmount - diff) + selItemsDimArray[i - 1].calcDistance
            };
        };


        //Check if element needs to actually move or not. If yes, move it - Use "calcDistance" property that was calculated earlier.
        for (var i = 1; i < selItemsDimArray.length; i++) {
            var aboutCompare = selItemsDimArray[i].diff.toFixed(compPrecision); //Strip off unnecessary decimal points - We don't need to split atoms.
            if (aboutCompare != trackingAmount) {          
                svgCanvas.moveSingleElement(selItemsDimArray[i].examinedElem, selItemsDimArray[i].calcDistance, 0, true); //moveSingleElement moves an element by an x,y value.
            }
        }

//Check if elements really reached their final position? Check is done by averaging all the elements current spacing.
       var average=0;
       for (var i = 0; i < selItemsDimArray.length; i++) {
        if(typeof selItemsDimArray[i].diff !== 'undefined'){
            average = average+selItemsDimArray[i].diff;
 };
       };

       average = average/(selItemsDimArray.length-1);

       //if the average spacing is not the same as the tracking we need, run again the whole algorithm. 
       if (Math.abs(average - trackingAmount) > trackTolerance){
        calcMultiTrack();
       }
    }
    //End of algorithm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up on *I will show this to a client*

- Run this through a jsbeautifier for indenting, also 2 new lines is overkill in code
- Run this code through jshint, the biggest detractors are

  - `selItemsDimArray[i]['calcDistance']` should be `selItemsDimArray[i].calcDistance`
  - Both missing and extraneous semicolons

Furthermore, from a once over:

- `var trackingAmount = parseInt($("#tracking").val());` either use a radix for `parseInt` or stop using `parseInt` and use `+` instead: 
  `var trackingAmount = +$("#tracking").val());`
- I am for commenting, but, comments have to add value, this does not add value:

  ```
  //Define new empty array
  var selItemsDimArray = [];
  ```
- I think `Math.abs` could help here:

  ```
      if (diff < 0) {
          selItemsDimArray[i]['calcDistance'] = (trackingAmount + (-diff)) + selItemsDimArray[i - 1].calcDistance
      } else {
          selItemsDimArray[i]['calcDistance'] = (trackingAmount - diff) + selItemsDimArray[i - 1].calcDistance
      };
  ```
- `for (var i = 1; i < selItemsDimArray.length; i++) {` <- You have this loop twice, you should merge those 2 loops
- This is interesting:

  ```
  //if the average spacing is not the same as the tracking we need, run again the whole algorithm. 
  if (Math.abs(average - trackingAmount) > trackTolerance){
    calcMultiTrack();
  }
  ```

You are using recursive calls here for no good reason, you should work this into a `while` statement inside your function.